# An easy if-statement

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement

So there is probably a really easy solution to this, but I'm trying to get a message in a P when two players are inputted.. So far I've got this(some norwegian words there, sorry):

`var spillere = [];`

```
function myFunction() {
if(spillere.length > 0) {
 document.getElementById("printAppear").innerHTML = '<button onclick="Printresultat()">Print resultat</button>';
 }
if(spillere.length < 2) {
    var player_navn = document.getElementById('navn').value;
    var player_poeng = document.getElementById('poeng').value;
    spillere.push([player_navn, parseFloat(player_poeng)]);

    spillere.sort(function(a,b){ 
        return a[1] - b[1];
    });


    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "";
    for(i = 0; i < spillere.length; i++) {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += (i+1) + ". " + spillere[i][0] + " - " + spillere[i][1] + " poeng<br />"; 
    }

}
```

So I'm basically just wanting to get a text where it says "Congratulations" and then the name of the player who won in this:

```
<p id="vinner"></p>
```

spillere=players and vinner=winner

Hope you understand what I'm trying to do

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! This question has several down votes because it's not clear what you are asking. What have you tried so far? What is your output? What is the expected output? Please post *all* relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

You could just add this line to the end of the function and assign the words you need and the name from first item of the array, which is obviously sorted by points.

```
document.getElementById("vinner").innerHTML = "Congratulations " + spillere[0][0];
```

Edit, just with testing length of the array of having 8 items:

```
if (spillere.length === 8) {
    document.getElementById("vinner").innerHTML = "Congratulations " + spillere[0][0];
}
```

Comment: Oh that was embarrasingly easy.. But how can I make it so that the sentence only appears when I've entered eight inputs? Now it just pops up when I make the first entry..